# How to animate vertically scrolling dynamic text array?

Tags: wpf, animation, dynamic-data, vertical-scrolling

I have an "array" of text which dynamically grows as data comes into the application, and I would like to be able to scroll (programmatically, not via direct user input) that array vertically, as well as add to it. I tried to put the data into a `DataGrid` but that's not really what I want (unless I heavily modify the DG which I'm hoping to avoid).  I don't need the array contents to be selectable, just viewable and I will scroll the "current" array item into view.  What WPF element(s) should I be using to display and dynamically grow the list?

Edit:
So here is my current XAML snippet:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFF8D2D2" ClipToBounds="True">
        <ItemsControl Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Name="PipeQueueIC" Height="45" Width="272" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF149060" />
</Canvas>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
DoubleAnimation scrollQueue = new DoubleAnimation();
scrollQueue.By = -16;
scrollQueue.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
PipeQueueIC.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, scrollQueue);
```

However the whole `ItemsControl` is moved up and it does not "scroll" through the "viewing window". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML. Also, you need to do this in MVVM using an ItemsControl, instead of using the horrible code-behind winforms type of hack.

Comment: Well, that's the thing - I'm not sure what XAML is right to use to contain this list of text items.  Once I figure out that, the animation will probably be pretty simple.

Comment: Remove the `Canvas` and use a `ScrollViewer`. And animate its offset instead.

Comment: @HighCore: Sorry - I am missing what you mean by "animate its offset."  I can't see any DP in `ScrollViewer` that matches that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListOfString}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> SomeListOfString {get;set;}

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //... Initialize and populate the Collection.
    }
}
```